# Verify reCaptcha google in FrontEnd php ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I'm trying to create a form with [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

Although I'm not an expert with javascript and ajax I succeed to cretae form and verify it with ajax before submit but when I added reCaptcha to my form I couldn't verify it FrontEnd. (In Backend, it works very well and the form is sent only if all field and captcha are all correctly filled)

I want to create something to alert user when he didn't fill the reCaptcha.
Below my code:

```
 /********** index.php *************/
    <?php  
     $siteKey = 'public key'; // votre clé publique 
     ?>
    <form action="process.php" id="contact" method="POST">


                <label  for="nom" class="label-style">Nom</label>
                <input class="w-input field-style" id="nom" name="nom" onkeyup="checkFilled('nom');" type="text">

                <span id="msg_nom"></span>


                <label for="email" class="label-style">Email</label>
                <input class="w-input field-style" id="email" name="email"  onkeyup="checkFilledEmail('email');" type="email">
                <span id="msg_email"></span>

                <label for="sujet" class="label-style" >Sujet</label>
                <input class="w-input field-style" id="sujet" name="sujet" onkeyup="checkFilled('sujet');" type="text">
                <span id="msg_sujet"></span>

                <label class="label-style" for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea class="w-input messageform" id="message" name="message" onkeyup="checkFilled('message');"  rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
                <span id="msg_message"></span>

                 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>"></div>
                 <span id="msg_captch"></span>
                <span id="msg_all"></span>
                <input class="w-button simple-button" type="submit" value="Envoyer" />

        </form>




         <script type="text/javascript">

        function checkFilled(variable) {
            var inputVal = document.getElementById(variable).value;
            if (inputVal == "") {
                document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "red";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "green";
            }
        }

        function checkFilledEmail(variable) {
            fld_value = document.getElementById(variable).value;
            is_m_valid = 0;
            if (fld_value.indexOf('@') >= 1) {

                m_valid_dom = fld_value.substr(fld_value.indexOf('@')+1).length;

                if (m_valid_dom >= 1) {

                    is_m_valid = 1;

                }

            }
            if (is_m_valid) {
               document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "green";
            } else {
               document.getElementById(variable).style.borderColor = "red";
            }

        }


            $(function(){
                $("#contact").submit(function(event){
                    var nom        = $("#nom").val();
                    var sujet      = $("#sujet").val();
                    var email      = $("#email").val();
                    var message    = $("#message").val();
                    var dataString = nom + sujet + email + message;
                    var captch     = $('.g-recaptcha').val();
                    var msg_all    = "Merci de remplir tous les champs";
                    var msg_alert  = "Merci de remplir le champs: ";
                    var msg_captch = " merci de remplir captcha";
                    $("#msg_all").html('');
                    $("#msg_nom").html('');
                    $("#msg_email").html('');
                    $("#msg_sujet").html('');
                    $("#msg_message").html('');

                 if(dataString  == "")
                    {
                        document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "red";
                        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
                        document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "red";
                        document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "red";

                        $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#msg_nom").offset().top
                                }, 500);

                    }
                    else if(nom == "")
                    {

                        var el10=document.getElementById('nom');
                        el10.style.borderColor = "red";



                    }

                    else if(email == "")
                    {

                        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
                    }
                     else if(sujet == "")
                    {

                        document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "red";
                    }

                    else if(message == "")
                    {

                        document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "red";
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url: $(this).attr("action"),
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success : function(){
                                $("#msg_all").html(" <p style='text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;'>Formulaire bien envoyé</p> ");
                                $(':input','#contact')
                                .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                                .val('');
                                $("#msg_nom").html('');
                                $("#msg_email").html('');
                                $("#msg_sujet").html('');
                                $("#msg_message").html('');
                                document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "";
                                $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#msg_nom").offset().top
                                }, 500);

                            },
                            error: function(){
                                $("#msg_all").html("<p style='text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;'>Erreur dappel, le formulaire ne peut pas fonctionner</p>");
                                document.getElementById('nom').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('sujet').style.borderColor = "";
                                document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

/************ process.php **************/

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<?php


require 'recaptchalib.php';

$secret = 'private key'; // votre clé privée


    // CONDITIONS NOM
    if ( (isset($_POST["nom"])) && (strlen(trim($_POST["nom"])) > 0) ):
        $nom = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST["nom"]));
    else:
        echo "Merci décrire un nom <br />";
        $nom = "";
    endif;

    // CONDITIONS SUJET
    if ( (isset($_POST["sujet"])) && (strlen(trim($_POST["sujet"])) > 0) ):
        $sujet = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST["sujet"]));
    else:
        echo "Merci décrire un sujet <br />";
        $sujet = "";
    endif;

    // CONDITIONS EMAIL
    if ( (isset($_POST["email"])) && (strlen(trim($_POST["email"])) > 0) && (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ):
        $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST["email"]));
    elseif (empty($_POST["email"])):
        echo "Merci décrire une adresse email <br />";
        $email = "";
    else:
        echo "Email invalide :(<br />";
        $email = "";
    endif;

    // CONDITIONS MESSAGE
    if ( (isset($_POST["message"])) && (strlen(trim($_POST["message"])) > 0) ):
        $message = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST["message"]));
    else:
        echo "Merci décrire un message<br />";
        $message = "";
    endif;

    $cap = 0;
    $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
    if(isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) 
    {
        $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
           $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
           $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
           );
        if ($resp != null && $resp->success) 
        {
           $cap = 1;
        }
        else
        {       
           echo "verify your CAPTCHA, it is incorrect <br />";
           $cap = 0;
        }

    }
    else 
    {
    echo "ERROR captcha <br />";
    $cap = 0;
    }

    // Les messages d"erreurs ci-dessus s'afficheront si Javascript est désactivé

    // PREPARATION DES DONNEES
    $ip           = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $hostname     = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
    $destinataire = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
    $objet        =  $sujet;
    $contenu      = "Nom de l'expéditeur : " . $nom . "\r\n";
    $contenu     .= $message . "\r\n\n";
    $contenu     .= "Adresse IP de l'expéditeur : " . $ip . "\r\n";
    $contenu     .= "DLSAM : " . $hostname;

    $headers  = "From: " . "contact@exemple.com" . " \r\n"; // ici l"expediteur du mail
    $headers  .= "Reply-to: " . $email . " \r\n"; // ici l"expediteur du mail
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; DelSp=Yes; format=flowed'. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Disposition: inline' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';

    // SI LES CHAMPS SONT MAL REMPLIS
   if ( (empty($nom)) && (empty($sujet)) && (empty($email)) && (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && (empty($message)) ):
        echo "echec";
   elseif ( $cap==0 ):
    echo "captcha error <br />";
// ENCAPSULATION DES DONNEES 
else:
        mail($destinataire,$objet,utf8_decode($contenu),$headers);
        echo "Formulaire envoyé";
        unset($_POST);
        unset($message);
        unset($sujet);
        unset($email);
        unset($nom);


endif;

    // Les messages d"erreurs ci-dessus s"afficheront si Javascript est désactivé
?>
```

What I want is:

To alert user who missed to check captcha exactly like I did  to verify other field before submit. I want to verify all my form before submitting ( In frontEnd). and the code above check all field  in frontEnd except of captcha.

How can I verify if captcha is checked or no in frontEnd.

Any info that allow me to keep coding.

Comment: What precisely is your problem? What have you tried? Why did you fail? Why can't you integrate those solutions into your code? Please improve your question by adding info on the actual problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, if We want to verify reCaptcha before submitting we have to add this simple code in submit (It will allow us to know if the reCaptcha is cheked or no):

```
var msg_captch = " You need to check Captcha";
var captch = jQuery('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
if(!captch)
    {
       $("#msg_captch").html(msg_captch);

    }
```

Please see the code above to know what is 'msg_captch'